# Need help on Overlapping Screenshot images

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

Looking for help here, i have a transparent picturebox (using fucshia as transparencyKey) named PB1  with PB1.Location.X = 145 , PB1.Location Y = 7 and a button named btnTakePic. The codes are as follows :

```
    Private Sub btnTakePic_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnTakePic.Click
    Dim Bound As Rectangle
    Dim Pic As Graphics
    Dim screenshot As System.Drawing.Bitmap
    Bound = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
    screenshot = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(PB1.Bounds.Width, PB1.Bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb)
    Pic = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot)
    Pic.CopyFromScreen(CInt(LocPBX.Text), CInt(LocPBY.Text), 0, 0, Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
    PB1.Image = screenshot
    PB1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
End Sub

Private Sub Main_LocationChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.LocationChanged
    LocX.Text = Me.Location.X
    LocY.Text = Me.Location.Y
    LocPBX.Text = Val(PB1.Location.X) + Val(LocX.Text) + 3
    LocPBY.Text = Val(PB1.Location.Y) + Val(LocY.Text + 25)
End Sub
```

Now the question is : it produces screenshot as exactly what i want, but when i click the btnTakePic , The picture will overlap the old one, I want to erase the old picture screenshot from memory and substituting it with a new one, how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear out the previous image and refresh the picturebox before taking a new shot:

```
Private Sub btnTakePic_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnTakePic.Click
    PB1.Image = Nothing
    PB1.Refresh()

    Dim pt As Point = PB1.PointToScreen(New Point(0, 0))
    Dim screenshot As New System.Drawing.Bitmap(PB1.Size.Width, PB1.Size.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb)
    Using Pic As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot)
        Pic.CopyFromScreen(pt.X, pt.Y, 0, 0, PB1.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
    End Using
    PB1.Image = screenshot
    PB1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
End Sub
```

How do you know what you're taking a picture of, though, if you already have a screenshot displayed?

Comment: Thanks mate, it works like charm, excellent. Yes, thank god you remind me, i add the clear image button.